# The evidence in from Mars

Tags: phrases, phrase-meaning

It's from ["The Mars Mystery" by Graham Hancock](http://catdir.loc.gov/catdir/samples/random044/98017933.html). Does the phrase "evidence in" have a special meaning?

> "The evidence in from Mars so far takes four principal forms:"

I'm afraid I don't see what additional meaning it gives by adding "in" **after** "evidence". It is understood that the evidence is from Mars (planet) and what kind of evidence exactly should be evident from the text around the quote.

Comment: I guess it's roughly the same as "so far", a suggestion that we've only got hold of so much of the available data, but that there may be more to come. A charitible reader would have less need of the "in".

Comment: Words don't have to give "additional" meaning to add to the "flow" of the sentence, or to avoid monotony.  However, "in", in this case, suggests the evidence is relatively recent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of *in* here is a stylized way of saying "coming in" cf. "I am just in."

Comment: I'd also add something about deletion/ellipsis to it.

Comment: As used in the sentence, closer to "The evidence (that has come) in from Mars so far takes four principal forms:". Also since the author uses "so far", I doubt they mean to say the evidence is particularly fresh or "just in".

Comment: It would be plain if we read the text around the quote that the 'evidence' could hardly be called 'recent'. It is rather '[generally ] accepted' , though I have no clues that it is  relevant when we discuss 'evidence in'.

I thought I understood the meaning. Now I realize that I did not.